# jsonrpc4j InvocationTargetException

Tags: exception, java

I'm using the [jsonrpc4j library](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j), and I've created a [basic demo](https://github.com/gaborbernat/json4j-rpc-test).

The problem is when the server throws an exception the framework forwards the client `InvocationTargetException` instead of the `source exception`.

I've created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j/issues/33) about this. In hope someone can point a quick solution I post it also as well. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved the issue. The problem was when using `CompositeService`. It wraps the exception thrown two times, and then it gets unwrapped only one time.

The fix is here:
https://github.com/bgaborg/jsonrpc4j/commit/a92c8a602d2c0b9957d0d3a59cd901785809a78e

### Edit:

In `JsonRpcServer.java` (inside `com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j` package), replace:

```
if (InvocationTargetException.class.isInstance(e))
```

with

```
while (InvocationTargetException.class.isInstance(e))
```